# How to pull in variable for order value into fulfilment company?

Tags: orders, transaction

Can anyone tell me how I can include the actual value of an order (not including shipping, although I might like that as an option as well) in an Order CSV that gets sent to the order fulfillment company? I am using Magento CE 1.8.1.

Basically when an order is generated, it also generates a CSV file with the order details and uploads this to the order fulfillment company. Looking through the code I can see that it pulls in other order data from variables e.g:

```
$billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress()->toArray();
$email = $billingAddress['email'];
$telephone = $billingAddress['telephone'];
```

What would be the variable name for pulling in the value of the order? I can't see any way of finding this out. I'm guessing it's $order -> something or other but I can't see any documentation on what the correct variable is?

Answer (score 1):

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114985/how-to-get-grand-total-without-shipping-costs-from-a-magento-order-model), the answer might be

```
$amount = $order->getGrandTotal() - $order->getShippingAmount();
```